# Javascript: parent/child window.close event not firing in Android stock browser

Tags: javascript, android, dom

all!

I'm having an issue with parent/child window communication on the stock Android 'Browser' browser. Safari, Chrome, Firefox, IE(!!!), iOS, all good! Android v4.1.1, not so much.

**The flow**:

1. From the parent, I open a child window, and add a loop to listen for the child window to close.
2. Child window closes, parent is notified.
3. Parent clears the loop, calls the handler.

Easy, right?

**The problem**: Android *can* call the `window.close()` from the child, but the parent is unaware of the close event, ie, step 3 never happens. <strike>Perhaps javascript is suspended in the parent while a child window is opened?</strike> Javascript is indeed running in the parent window. Is there a definitive fix or workaround for this problem?

**My CoffeeScript**:

```
openTwitterAuthWindow: (authURL) =>
    @twitterWindow = window.open(authURL, "_blank", "width=550,height=420")
    @checkInterval = window.setInterval(@checkChildWindow, 500)

checkChildWindow: () =>
    if (@twitterWindow && @twitterWindow.closed)
        alert("Excelsior!") # <-- Not called, unfortunately
        window.clearInterval(@checkInterval)
        @twGetLoginStatus()
```

**Only javascript inside the child window**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.close();
</script>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've suggested, it seems like the parent window doesn't know when the child window has closed. If the child window has closed however, the reference that the parent has to it would be null at that point so the following should work in Android:

```
openTwitterAuthWindow: (authURL) =>
    @twitterWindow = window.open(authURL, "_blank", "width=550,height=420")
    @checkInterval = window.setInterval(@checkChildWindow, 500)

checkChildWindow: () =>
    if (!@twitterWindow || @twitterWindow.closed)
        alert("Excelsior!")
        window.clearInterval(@checkInterval)
        @twGetLoginStatus()
```